# How to add attribute a value to my Combobox using vue Js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-select

My plugin (**vue-select@latest**)
I can successfully get data from the object  **cities** but how do I add a value , for example  `<span class="selected-tag" value="Moscow" or value="New York">`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDy77.png)

I'm new to Vue js , I want to use the plugin  vue-select , my problem is that I can not add the value attribute.
My attempts fail

```
 <v-select :options="locations" label="name" v-model="country" value="value" ></v-select>
```

I create a dynamic combobox  from the object cities: ['Moscow', 'Sp', 'Tomsk' , 'Voronezh', 'Novossibirsk'],

and I want all the data from the combobox to attribute value, for Example value="Moscow"

```
    let sample =new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    country: null,
    city: null,
    locations: [
      {
        name: 'Russia',
        cities: ['Moscow', 'Sp', 'Tomsk' , 'Voronezh', 'Novossibirsk'],
        value: ['Moscow', 'Sp', 'Tomsk' , 'Voronezh', 'Novossibirsk']
      },
      {
        name: 'USA',
        cities: ['LA', 'Pensacola', 'New York'],
        value: ['LA', 'Pensacola', 'New York']

      }
    ]
  },
```

[link to codepen](https://codepen.io/frontend33/pen/oyryWQ)
My cdn libary

```
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@latest"></script>
```

Comment: Value is v-model

Comment: value from the second combobox

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the options property needs to be an string array or a plain object array with "label" and "value" properties.

You can try this:

```
<v-select :options="locations.map(i => i.name)" label="name" v-model="country"></v-select>
```

It will show you a select with the name of your locations.

Comment: I can successfully display them, my task is to add them an attribute value

Comment: What do you mean by add them an attribute value?

Comment: <option value="Moscow">
 <option value="Tomsk">
<option value="Novossibirsk">
 <option value="Sp">